# Creating SQS Queue From Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create an SQS queue from a Lambda function in Python. I have the below code, and have run it locally with great success.

```
client = boto3.client('sqs')

notifications_url = client.create_queue(
    QueueName=notifications_queue,
    Attributes={
        'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': '20'
    }
)
```

I have uploaded the code as a Lambda function and am trying to run it from the Lambda console. When I run it, it times out after 30 seconds (30 second timeout) on the line above.

The Lambda function role has full SQS access, so I'm not worried about it being a permissions issue, but I'm not sure what else I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you place your Lambda function inside a VPC without a NAT Gateway?

Comment: I just added a NAT Gateway because I was having further issues making requests using the Python Requests library in my Lambda functions. I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12) and was unable to get the requests library working. So now my lambda functions are apart of a VPC which has subnets routed to an Internet Gateway, and also has subnets routed to a NAT Gateway.

Comment: @MarkB I'm still having issues with this. Any idea what other issues I may be having?

Comment: Does your function really need to be in a VPC? Does it need to access an EC2 instance or database in your VPC? If not then don't run it in a VPC. If you have to run it in a VPC then make sure it is in a private subnet that has a route to the NAT gateway. To test out that subnet place a temporary EC2 instance in it and see if it has Internet access. Otherwise, try to provide more info, like the actual logs from the Lambda function execution.

Comment: @MarkB it needs access to an RDS instance that I have running. I was having trouble connecting to the RDS instance without a VPC, so I threw it in a VPC, which solved the RDS connection issue. I just removed the function from the VPC, and I am now able to connect to the RDS instance and I have internet access on the Lambda function, but I have no clue why. I guess it could be because I put the RDS instance in a VPC that has access to 0.0.0.0/0 via an Internet gateway but I'm not sure if that's the best solution.

Comment: If you can access it outside a VPC then you enabled the "publicly accessible" flag on your RDS instance, and you probably opened up the security group on the RDS instance to the world. That's really not the most secure way to do this. Like I said, if you want help setting up the VPC then do what I said in my last comment, and if it doesn't work include more logs and details about your configuration.